# Transform single char arrays to one multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following declaration of arrays

```
char array1[10] = "Nick";
char array2[10] = "Tomas";
char array3[10] = "Nathan";
char array4[10] = "John";
char array5[10] = "Paul";
char *new_array[3][1];
```

I want to create a new table in this way

```
Nick Tomas
Nick Nathan
Nick John
Nick Paul
```

First of all is my declaration of new_array correct? Secondly I tried something like that until now which of course is not correct

```
for (j = 0; j<4; ++j)
    {
        new_array[j][k]=array1;
        for (k = 0; k<2; ++k)
        {
            new_array[j][k]=array2;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j<4; ++j)
        for (k = 0; k<2; ++k)
        {
            printf("%s\t", new_array[j][k]);
            if(j==1)
            printf("\n");
        }
```

I would like a solution or some details how to do it using for loop

Comment: No, the `new_array` declaration is not correct. The size of the outer array is to small for the actual data.

Comment: loop is not possible because you are input string are individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply something like

```
char *new_array[][2] = {
    { array1, array2 },
    { array1, array3 },
    { array1, array4 },
    { array1, array5 }
};
```

---

To get the number of entries in this array, you can use

```
sizeof(new_array) / sizeof(new_arrag[0])
```

However, if you pass this array as an argument to a function it decays to a pointer, and that "trick" can't be used. Instead you have to pass the number along with the array.

---

To print it, two entries at a time, something like this could be used:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(new_array) / sizeof(new_arrag[0]); i += 2)
    printf("%s %s\n", new_array[i], new_array[i + 1]);
```

Comment: What about `NULL`-terminating `new_array`?

Comment: @alk I see nothing in the code or question of the OP suggesting it's needed, but it's just to add a `{ NULL, NULL }` line last in the array initialization.

Comment: @alk You should be able to take `sizeof(new_array)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and how can I print this array? A simple printf("Array:%s",new_array) or something like that?

Comment: @dali1985 Updated my answer with an example loop